# htaccess rewrite to reverse subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**As basic as it gets, here is an example of what I'm trying to do:**
[image]

I have a structure that takes different types of CMS' and inside each of those installations, are language variations.

By default the structure looks like this:
`https://[domain]/[country]/[installation]/[language-code]`

Ultimately, I'm trying to get this:

`https://[domain]/[country]/[language-code]/[installation]/`

I'm wondering if this can be accomplished, due to the fact the folders/languages themselves are not actual folders and in fact rewrites from the CMS' settings (within the subfolders).

As unmodified these would be examples of the current urls:

```
https://example.com/ca/events/en/
https://example.com/ca/store/en/
https://example.com/ca/network/en/
```

And example of the desired results:

```
https://example.com/ca/en/events/
https://example.com/ca/en/store/
https://example.com/ca/en/network/
```

and for each installation, they dont always have the same languages (eg. ca has en and fr, but us has en and es)

Note: subsequent pages would be appended... eg:
`https://example.com/ca/en/events/event-name/subpage/`

Comment: So what should happen to `https://example.com/ca/events/`?

Comment: @anubhava that is an example of an installation folder ```https://example.com/ca/events/``` which has subsequent languages ```https://example.com/ca/events/en/``` which really should be:  ```https://example.com/ca/en/events/```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be be able to use this single redirect rule on top of your .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.+)/([a-z]{2}/?)$ $1/$3/$2 [L]
```

Comment: I really appreciate your response ; I'm looking for a rewrite rather than a redirect - as the above seems to redirect to the desired result, but also results in a 404 because the folders do not actually exist.

Comment: ok I have converted external redirect to a rewrite but what is purpose of this rewrite if external URL is still `/ca/events/en/` ?

Comment: Generally the purpose behind this is to establish a standard naming convention.  [COUNTRY][LANGUAGE][APP-NAME]. but since the app controls the locale/language ; it puts it after the app.    I may need to look more closely at modifying the application's .htaccess instead of using the root level.   ```/ca/events/``` is a joomla  application (in most cases) which has its own rewrite rules.

Comment: This solution is tested as working under the conditions that were described in the question.  Although it did not resolve my problem specifically, its a working solution - and has unveild the greater issue within the CMS.  I will need to redirect this issue to be more CMS Specific, thank you very much anubhava. The new thread is located here: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=987230